# Building nested dictionaries to dump it to .json later

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, hash-map

I am looking for some way to improve my code. It works but it doesn't look good and I am almost sure that lot of Best Practices rules are violated.

The `save_session()` function, creates dictionary with other dictionaries nested in. At the end the dictionary is dump to .json file.

**I will appreciate any suggestions and advice for improvement of this code.**

For better understanding the code of `save_session()`:

`workouts_instances` is the list of current `WorkoutPlan` instances,

`WorkoutPlan` stores instances of `Training` and `Exercise`,

`Training` stores instances of `Exercise`,

```py
class WorkoutPlan:
    def __init__(self, name, trainings=list(), exercises=list()):
        self.name = name
        self.trainings = trainings
        self.exercises = exercises
    ...

class Training:
    def __init__(self, name, exercises=list()):
        self.name = name
        self.exercises = exercises
    ...

class Exercise:
    def __init__(self, name, details=dict()):
        self.name = name
        self.details = details
    ...
```

Here is the code of `save_session()`:

```py
def save_session():
    """Exports current data to .json file."""
    data_to_save = {}

    # add workout plans
    for workout in workouts_instances:
        data_to_save[workout.name] = {}

        # add trainings
        if workout.trainings:
            data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"] = {}

            for training in workout.trainings:
                data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name] = {}

                # add training exercises
                if training.exercises:
                    data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name]['exercises'] = {
                        exercise.name: {} for exercise in training.exercises
                    }

                    for exercise in training.exercises:

                        if exercise.details:
                            data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name]['exercises'][exercise.name][
                                'details'] = {detail: value for detail, value in
                                              exercise.details.items()}

        # add exercises
        if workout.exercises:
            data_to_save[workout.name]["exercises"] = {}

            exercises_to_save = data_to_save[workout.name]["exercises"]

            for exercise in workout.exercises:
                exercises_to_save[exercise.name] = {}

                if exercise.details:
                    details = exercise.details
                    exercises_to_save[exercise.name]['details'] = {detail: value for detail, value in details.items()}

    with open(WORKOUTS_FILE, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data_to_save, json_file, indent=4)
```

and here is the example of output, data stored in .json file:

```
{
    "FBV - Full Body Workout": {
        "trainings": {
            "Training A": {
                "exercises": {
                    "squats": {
                        "details": {
                            "description": "squats with barbell",
                            "series": 4,
                            "repeats": 4,
                            "load": 70
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "exercises": {
            "some exercise name": {
                "details": {
                    "description": "some description",
                    "series": 5,
                    "repeats": 5,
                    "load": 60
                }
            },
            "bench press - wide": {
                "details": {
                    "description": "bench press with wide grip",
                    "series": 5,
                    "repeats": 5,
                    "load": 60
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide the code calling the function or example usage as well.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: ```save_session()``` is one of the menu options in console app. All it has to do is to write data into dictionaries and dump it to .json later.
All I want to know is how to build this dictionary of nested dictionaries in more proper way than it is right now.

Comment: Right now the question is off-topic please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. By asking for examples of use I was trying to improve the question.

Comment: Simply put, if you add example input and output it means it's easier for people to understand the transformation that is happening - help us, help you.

Comment: I made some edits. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Do not use [mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145781/96588), they will mess with your subsequent calls. There are some very rare cases where mutable default arguments make sense, but this does not look like one of those.
- Split generation of data from saving that data to a file. That way either method can be reused. If you also pull out the file handle to a `main` method you can dependency inject the file handle and test the whole functionality.
- `details` have the same pattern everywhere, so they should also be a class or should be part of `Exercise`.
- Like most Python code this could benefit from type annotations using MyPy.